# Can I make javascript think that I'm running on localhost?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function on a website that I want to attack which is called every time if we log something. So, if we are running on localhost then, `window.location.href.substr(7, 9)` is `"localhost"`. Can I make the website think that I'm running on localhost? I want to do this because `redlog()` is often called for logging sensitive information.

```
function redlog(s) {
    if (window.location.href.substr(7, 9) == "localhost") {
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript in the browser runs on the local machine. Do you mean you want the javascript in your browser to run on the server? I'm still very confused about where the script is running and where you want it to think it is running.

Comment: @schroeder It checks that if in the URL there is localhost. But obviously, it's not localhost, because it's not running on my computer, it's running on a server. I want to make it think that it's running on my computer.

Comment: And where is this javascript? It's downloaded to the browser on your computer, right? Then, just strip out that line or modify it to whatever you want...?

Comment: @schroeder What do you mean? If you right-click and inspect the page, then go-to sources, you can't edit it there. I mean you can edit it there, but it won't make changes.

Comment: @schroeder If I delete the whole line and then write `redlog` to console, it will still know the function.

Comment: @schroeder By "whole line" I mean the whole function.

Comment: You have an XY Problem. You want to do X but are asking about Y because of Z. What you want to know is how to modify Javascript that is executing in your browser. Ultimately, this is not a security question. If you reframe your problem as that, you will find a thousand different resources for do this.

Comment: Secondly, I'm confused about the entire foundation for the question. The things that this function logs are from the client, right? Why do you need to "attack" yourself? You already have access to the dataflows on the client without needing to modify this one script. Are you thinking that you will get the sensitive data from the ***server***?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is executed in your browser. `Console.log()` writes to the javascript console in your browser.

You can trivially edit javascript that your browser runs. Simply rewrite it to

```
function redlog(s) {
   console.log(s);
}
```

There are *frameworks* for doing this, such as [Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey) or [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

Comment: As far as I understand I should write a user script. Am I right?

Comment: There's *many* ways to skin a cat. Userscript is one way in this case.